# How to train tree of stages classifiers instead of cascade in OpenCV for face detection?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, cascade-classifier

I found in `haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree` xml as the xml file is trained with train tree of stages classifiers instead of cascade. I am wondering how to train for tree of stages classifier in `OpenCV`, which api to use and any example available for that. I searched and no proper information is found so far.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opencv [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) is pretty clear about cascade training with weak tree possible tunings. "opencv_traincascade" is the API training function. "Boosted classifer parameters" is what your are looking for, especially "max_depth_of_weak_tree" and "max_weak_tree_count".

Comment: Any idea, how to get decision tree for multiple classes detection such as multiple view face detection.

Comment: If you want to continue with Boosting algorithms for classification, you should read about Gradient Boosted Trees which can deal with multiclass classification. There is an OpenCV implementation of GBT.

Comment: Yes that is another option. My application has speed concern as it will be running inside an embedded platform. So I used LBP features rather than Haar. Then in this paper (http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/2371001.aspx) Viola and Jones used C4.5 tree classifier. Any idea how to train C4.5 decision tree for multiple view face detection. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps see this old post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757202/looking-for-a-c-implementation-of-the-c4-5-algorithm

Comment: It is true that LBP-based cascade is a little faster than Haar-based cascade. However you will have in general a 10% drop of accuracy.